# Flask can not render umlauts

Tags: encoding, utf-8, flask, jinja2

There seems to be no way to render umlauts in Flask.
I have 2 files:

main.py (the Flask app):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from data import d

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return jsonify(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

data.py (containing data with umlauts):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

d = {u'str': u'äöüß'}
```

runnig main.py the output in the browser is:

```
{
  "str": "\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df"
}
```

Is there any way to display 'äöüß' ?

Thanks Eriq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but take a look at the [configuration values](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values) for Flask. In particular, setting `JSON_AS_ASCII` to `False` should let you use `jsonify` just the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jsonify, use json.dumps as follows.

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=False)
```

The ensure_ascii parameter takes care of whether you want to display ascii or not.